# JavaScript HTML Editor for Wiki-like Site?

Tags: ckeditor, html-parsing, html-editor, markitup

I have a wiki-like site where users can post and edit.  I need a good HTML editor.  I've tried [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and it was problematic because people often cut and paste.  They take with them styles and javascript that conflict with the surrounding HTML and with what I only want to allow (no changing colors, etc).  Maybe there's a way to configure CKEditor to do what I need, but it wasn't obvious how from their documentation.  This was over a year ago though..

My requirements are the following:

- Only allow a small subset of HTML (simple paragraphs with inline formatting for italics, etc., images that are hosted by us and links internal to our site)
- As clean xhtml as possible
- Prefer (x)html, but I'm open to alternate markup
- Using jQuery, so if the editor relies on jQuery that's preferable
- Internationalizable
- WYSIWYG is nice, but maybe it helps to avoid copy/paste issues by not having WYSIWYG?

The most important thing is to not allow users to inadvertently or purposely screw things up, usually through copying and pasting other webpages or word documents.  [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) looks really nice, the lack of WYSIWYG has me on the fence.  I love [WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org)'s focus on clean xhtml, but it still does allow craziness when copying and pasting from the demos and there doesn't seem to be much activity for the past 6 months or so.

StackOverflow's editor might be good for us too.  Like markItUp!, it's not WYSIWYG, but it is very simple.  I understand they took WMD-editor and updated it.  The non-html aspect means an easier time on the server side parsing out potentially harmful code...

What do you guys think?  What's the best solution out there for a wiki-like site editor?

Answer (score 0):

You should try again CKEditor after enabling [forcePasteAsPlainText](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.forcePasteAsPlainText)